# TextView.Text will not update visually on screen when changed

Tags: java, c#, android

```
public void displayTimeOnScreen()
    {
        _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        _timer.Interval = 1000;
        _timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
        _timer.Enabled = true;
        FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewDay).Text = "Test";//This works
    }

public void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextView timeTextView, dateTextView, dayTextView;

        LinearLayout screen = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.box);
        bool portrate = screen.Height > screen.Width;

        timeTextView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewTime);
        dateTextView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewDate);
        dayTextView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewDay);

        string[] timeData = { "stuff", "things", "test" };

        timeTextView.Text = timeData[0];
        dateTextView.Text = timeData[1];
        dayTextView.Text = timeData[2];
        Log.Info("Information", timeTextView.Text);//This will tell me that timeTextView.Text has actually been updated, it just isn't showing on the screen
    }
}
```

So I have been trying to make a simple program that displays the time on an android device. I am using a `Timers` object to run the code that should update the time. However, although `Log` is telling me that the code is being run and that the text value of the `TextView` is being updated, this isn't showing on the screen of the android device. The one the `displayTimeOnScreen()` method does work however.

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

The method your are looking for is `textView.setText()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `setText()` to display text in your `TextView`.

```
timeTextView.setText(timeData[0]);
dateTextView.setText(timeData[1]);
dayTextView.setText(timeData[2]);
```

Comment: I have tried `setText()` and I have exactly the same problem. `TextView.Text = string` definitely works because the the one in the `displayTimeOnScreen()` method does change the text. I am pretty sure it has something to do with the Timer but no idea what.